# Where is Open in browser button in iOS app?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, ios-app

Open in browser button has been disappeared for any posts:

> [image: nobut]

Also I noticed that "Share" button now looks like "Open in browser" for old versions:

> [image: old]

- App Version: 1.6.6
- Device: iPad Air 2 (Wi-Fi)
- OS Version: Version 10.3.1 (Build 14E304)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oops... now I see it inside "Share" button:

> [image: share more]

Comment: Yep.  I recently added browsers to the share sheet and some people internally expressed confusion about "Open in {browser}" not prompting to selected the default browser on first use, so it seemed like an okay time to retire it.  It seems like most apps have gone this direction for reopening content in a browser.