# Is it possible to see posts I wrote that were deleted when I'm using an iPhone?

Tags: support, ios-app, deleted-posts

Can I see the posts that I wrote that have been deleted - either by myself or other users when on an iPhone? I’m asking this because, I'm using the iPhone 6 and when I try to find posts that I created on the site through iPhone, I get this message:

> *Page not found, possible explanations why a question might be removed*.

This is odd because, when I open my laptop, I can find these posts but they don't show up on my iPhone? Why? Is there a link to them or some way I can see the deleted posts on my phone?

Comment: Sounds like you were using a different account from your phone than the account you used from the desktop.

Comment: @Catija I’m using IOS app

Comment: @Servy I have the same account, even if I’m on laptop, the same account I have on Iphone. You know what I’m trying to say?

Comment: @Catija Yes, about my posts I’m talking about. Which I have deleted some of them and now I count to know that I did a mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You can't see deleted questions in the Stack Exchange iOS app. From [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/192385/284336):

> At this time we'll be supporting what is available through our public API - which is only content that has not been deleted. It's possible we may change this later to support > 10K users however this will not be in V1.0

You can switch to full site view in a browser and see them just fine, though, which is why the link to Safari is on every post. If you can't find the question at all, you'll just have to browse the site directly in Safari or whichever iOS browser you use.

Comment: Ok, I can try this

Comment: Can you show me how to do that, please?

Comment: Click on "share".

Comment: Ok, and where is that?

Comment: It's on every single post in the app. Open any post and you should see it.

Comment: Sorry, I couldn’t find it. It is sometimes difficult for me to find something in this app.

Comment: @Dreadbot look [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/296070/339911)

Comment: @Catija Can you please tell me how to see the list of self deleted questions on Meta? If no, can you please show me a list of my deleted questions? So that I can fix them.